# Reload the contents of the datatable after update or delete opertaion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I want to reload the content of my datatable after updating or deleting data into or from the database. I used fnDraw() but it not working. I done the deletion using ajax. Here is my code

ajax.php

```
<?php 
$mysql_host = 'localhost'; 
$mysql_database = 'proj1'; 
$mysql_user = 'root'; 
$mysql_password='';
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
{
echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 $id=$_POST['id'];
 $delete = "delete from regestration_details where eid=".$id."";
 $ss=mysqli_query( $mysqli,$delete);
?>
```

jquery_ajax.js

```
$('#myTable').on('click','.b2',function()
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) 
    {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = {id : id };
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_delete.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function()
        {
            $("#myTable").dataTable().fnDraw();
            alert("datas are successfully deleted..");
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("Error occured..");   
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Any idea for the above problem..?

Comment: What you could do is after you have deleted or updated something generate the new table in javascript and than show that on the page

Comment: @SuperDJ why we can't use the fnDraw()..?